# Android Launch canceled! Error in console

Tags: android, adb, uninstallation, launch

When I run the application on Device/Emulator getting error as

```
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures. [2011-04-19 10:11:20 - enga] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data! [2011-04-19 10:11:20 - enga] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.engatest' in a shell. Launch canceled!
```

Executed the command in Terminal. But the error still Exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to uninstall application from device maually. If still the problem exists Change your Package name. Hope that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use in a root shell to remove completely

> pm uninstall PACK.AGE.NAME

in your case

> pm uninstall com.engatest